# flex direction row items overflow how to fix this?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have two rows, 1st one contains image and second one text. So when I use flexDirection: 'row' the text overflow the width and ellipsis not showing. Please have a look into my code.

```
<View style={styles.boxContainer}>
    <View style={{marginRight: 10}}>
        <Text style={{textAlign: 'left'}}>
            <Image
                style={styles.eventImg}
                source={{uri: item.image}}
            />
        </Text>
    </View>
    <View>
        <Text style={{fontSize: 16, fontWeight: '500'}}>{item.title}</Text>
        <Text style={{fontSize: 12, color: '#878787'}}>{item.formatted_date}</Text>
        <Text style={{fontSize: 10}} numberOfLines={1} ellipsizeMode='tail'>{item.descr}</Text>
        <View style={{flexDirection: 'row'}}>
            <TouchableOpacity
                onPress={() =>
                    this.onPressReadMore(item.id)
                }
            >
                <Text style={{fontSize: 12, padding: 5, backgroundColor: '#76ac42', color: '#ffffff', borderRadius: 3, textAlign: 'center', marginTop: 10, width: 80}}>Read More</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
            <Text style={{alignSelf: 'center', textAlign: 'right'}}>Registered</Text>
        </View>
    </View>
</View>
```

styles

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
container: {
    backgroundColor: '#ffffff'
},
tabContainer: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    marginTop: 10,
    marginBottom: 10,
    marginLeft: 10,
    marginRight: 10
},
tabSingle: {
    flex: 1,
    marginBottom: 5
},
titleText: {
    fontSize: 20,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    textAlign: 'left',
    paddingTop: 20,
    paddingLeft: 20,
    paddingRight: 20
},
boxContainer: {
    backgroundColor: '#f6f6f6',
    padding: 10,
    marginBottom: 10,
    marginLeft: 10,
    marginRight: 10,
    flexDirection: 'row',
    borderRadius: 5
},
eventImg: {
    width: 80,
    height: 80,
    resizeMode: 'cover',
    borderRadius: 5
}
});
```

Where am going wrong. I have tried many article and none of them seems working. Is there any way to fix this. Please have a look into the design,

[image: Overflow]

Comment: `flexWrap: 'wrap'`

Comment: where to place it, inside `boxContainer`? @VaibhavVishal

Comment: What design do you want? Do you have a reference picture?

Comment: @hongdevelop The same image attached. In the image `Registered` text should be on the right side.

Comment: @JithinVarghese Try a marginLeft: 'auto' instead of the alignSelf: 'center', textAlign: 'right'. Or alignSelf: 'flex-end'.

Comment: @KevinEtore Now the `Registered` text aligned right, but it is not visible because of overflow. Is there any way to fix this.

Comment: @JithinVarghese Can you add another print screen?

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
<View style={{flexDirection:'row'}}>
    <Text style={{fontSize: 10, flex: 1, flexWrap: 'wrap', flexShrink: 1}} ellipsizeMode='tail'>
        {item.descr}
    </Text>
</View>
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the horizontal value in `View`, which contains the ellipsis.

```js
 <View style={{width: 200}} >
       ....
        <Text style={{fontSize: 10}} numberOfLines={1} ellipsizeMode='tail'>{item.descr}
</Text>
```

Here's an example of a [word-for-word abbreviation](https://snack.expo.io/ByiP0w4QH) I've simplified.

Comment: if we add width it will break in different screen sizes

Comment: Add the width to the style of the box container.